# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' Error in in xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

I'm following the tutorial on https://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial and all I've done is copy and paste yet I'm getting the error below:

**Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 107; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.**

This is what my XML file looks like up until thee 7th line where the error is referencing to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what's causing this error? Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if u need any more information to answer this.

Comment: Your tutorial is severely obsolete. Spring XML configuration in general is old-style, and Java 6 has been end-of-life for _more than seven years_. The current version of Spring is 5.2, with 5.3 nearly ready. Instead, try [this current official Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- ok I will look into that one, thanks